# Using regular expression for fetching multiple keywords using python 3.4

Tags: python, regex, excel

I am using python 3.4 in windows 7. 
I have excel sheet in which data is present in every cell.
The data is of different kinds .Two examples :- `"Qwert A_B_C_1 uiop"`    and `"Qwert A_X_Y_Z uiop"`

To sum up i have to extract keywords which are written in CAPS where just after the first word an underscore is present. The extracting should stop once a whitespace is encountered

I have tried something like this but

```
x =  "QWERT A_B_C_1 UIOP"
se = re.findall("[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+_[0-9A-Z]+",x)
```

But it is not working with different types of keywords.

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: It works; should print `A_B_C_1`. What's the problem?

Comment: @Maroun Maroun - what if i dont know as to how many words and underscores are present after A_. How can i read the entire keyword till a whitespace is encountered.??

Comment: @vks the expected output is the keyword written in caps starting with A_

Comment: answer added........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*_[A-Z0-9]+
```

You can use this to capture variable `_[A-Z]` in between.[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/wX9fR1/27)

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*_[A-Z0-9]+')
test_str = "QWERT A_B_C_1 UIOP\nQwert A_X_Y_Z uiop"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I explored more options and came up with

lst = re.findall('\S+_\S+', test_str)

Works as expected.....

Comment: This will match `!@#!@#_!@#####!@#` that's it.Iw wont match `A_B_C_D`.it will give that as a list of broken elements